# How to set pop up using Angular Js + bootsrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing a site in angular js and bootsrap.

When site loads I am doing some server call to get some data. This process took some time. In this time interval I want to show a pop up with waiting message.

But I am stuck how do here with my setup.
in app.js, in run method I want to add popup call to show and hide once execution completed.

```
.run(["$log", "$rootScope", "$state", "dtoResource", "questionResource", function ($log, $rootScope, $state, dtoResource, questionResource) {
                    dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO()
                            .then(function (data) {
                                $rootScope.AutoQuote = data;
                                questionResource.getQuestions($rootScope.AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode)
                                        .then(function (questions) {
                                           $rootScope.questions = questions;
                                            $rootScope.answers = {PC: 12345};
                                              console.log('Copy operation');
                                 angular.copy($rootScope.answers,$rootScope.default);
                                 console.log($rootScope.answers);
                                 console.log($rootScope.default);
                                           })
                            })
                            .then(function () {
                                //console.log('This should be printed after the above methods are done     executing');
                               // console.log($rootScope);

                            })

                }])
Below is plunker link
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You need include the angular-bootstrap $uibmodal module in your app and then you are ready to

Open on a modal on the call of the save method. The method below does the job.

```
var instance = $modal.open();
```

Hold on to the instance and call it appropriately on the response of your save.

```
instance.dismiss();
```

The above will close your informative popup.

Have a look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YporEEYfgnVg4WhZXm5Z?p=preview) I have created for you. It is rather quick at getting your ip adderess but it mimics your solution.

Comment: Can I create pop up without using ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.1.js, 1.5.8/angular-animate.js,1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js fro simple things this looks overhead on application.

Comment: I agree it is a little overhead. You can drop the angular-animate but you need the template. And if you are not using Sanitize already then you are missing out on angular's features.

Comment: For now whatever I am using is there in my plunker.

Comment: I was expecting solution like a responsive div with ng-show /hide. this would not require extra inclusion

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
<div id="loading" class="hidden"><p>loading</p></div>
```

in your HTML code.

before making the server add the following :

```
$("#loading").removeClass("hidden");
```

and just after receiving the response from server add :

```
$("#loading").addClass("hidden");
```